# Heroku deploy Ruby app: failed to push some refs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment

I try to deploy my ruby app. I'm getting this error:

```
[X] Shell command exited with status code 32512!

=====================[ CRASH REPORT ]=====================

COMMAND:
cd /tmp/build_b8047ce119e9ca6cd5474afa9f1e57f9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bundler/gems/accounting-d82701194c3b
The latest bundler is 1.15.3, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
To update, run `gem install bundler`/accounting-frontend && yarn install

ERROR:


==========================================================

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Run app.

 !     Push failed
Verifying deploy...

 !  Push rejected to my-app-dev.

To https://git.heroku.com/my-app-dev.git
 ! [remote rejected]   24f2f837b3645a2c10bf2484322f8dd5d36ad2d5 -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/my-app-dev.git'
    to retry, use: --limit @/Users/username/repositories/sd/playbooks/my-app/dev.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

I have a few repositories which are included as gems (like `accounting` what you will read in the messages above).

I thought I need to rebuild my `Gemfile.lock` with the bundler version 1.15.2. That didn't help.

As the error says the app couldn't be compiled. Do you know why or do you know a good way to figure out the real issue?

I'm not that familiar with deploying so if there are some information you need please leave a comment and I will update this question.

Comment: Is accounting a gem you keep in a private repo? If that's the case you need to use a buildpack. Check out [this one](https://github.com/AutoUncle/heroku-buildpack-github-netrc)

Comment: Also try to paste `heroku logs`. They might contain some useful information to debug this.

Comment: Yes, accounting is a private repo included as a gem. It is hosted on Gitlab. I will search for a buildpack for Gitlab.

Comment: That's the problem for sure. Unfortunately I can't help with Gitlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. As the log says it can't find the commands `The` and `To`. You can see the warning about the bundler version. Both lines start with these words. So the script tried to run those lines as well. That was some inter problems of my scripts.

I run `bundle show GEMNAME` and used that output as a path for `cd`. The ouput contained the warning about the bundler version which I used in the path. Fixed that now with using only the first line of the output.

Answer (score 0):

This might be issue with your gemfile.lock file. If you have added any gems do bundle install then `git add`, `git commit` and push to Heroku.

If the above solution not working try to do `rake assets:precompile` and then `git add`, `git commit` and `git push`.

If this also doesn't work then issue might be with your script files. I mean JavaScript/jQuery/CoffeeScript files. Try to compile script files for any error in local.

```
js_path = "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/javascripts/**/*.js"; 
Dir[js_path].each do |file_name|
  puts "\n#{file_name}"
  puts Uglifier.compile(File.read(file_name))
end
```